# Some trouble in struct _stack* and Digit::struct_stack*

Tags: c++, class, oop, struct

```
void Digit::push(int value){

    struct _stack *next_field = new struct _stack;
    if (end == nullptr && start == nullptr){
        next_field->_next_ptr = nullptr; //in codebloks project. next_ptr = himself
        start = next_field;
    }
    else
        next_field->_next_ptr = end;
    next_field->_data = value;
    end = next_field;
}
```

The error that shows up is:

> assigning to 'struct _stack *' (aka '_stack *') from incompatible type
>   'struct _stack *' (aka 'Digit::_stack *')

How can I fix it ?

This is Header Digit class:

```
class Digit
{
    struct _stack *start = nullptr;
    struct _stack *end = nullptr;
    struct _stack *ptr_element = nullptr;

    struct _stack {
        _stack* _next_ptr = nullptr;
        int _data = 0;
    }_element;

public:
    Digit();
    void push(int);
    void pop();
};
```

Comment: Please change the title of your question, so that it becomes more relevant.

Comment: And stop writing C struct in C++, just use `_stack`. And change the name...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler regards `struct _stack` and `struct _stack` within `class Digit` as two different entities.

To resolve this, move the definition of `struct _stack` within `class Digit` before the declaration of the pointers. The class should look like this:

```
class Digit
{
    struct _stack {
        _stack* _next_ptr = nullptr;
        int _data = 0;
    }_element;

    struct _stack *start = nullptr;
    struct _stack *end = nullptr;
    struct _stack *ptr_element = nullptr;   

public:
    Digit();
    void push(int);
    void pop();
};
```

[See **Demo**](https://godbolt.org/z/My34ox)